# Multiple hardware devices under Xen Hypervisor

Tags: xen

this might sound like a dumb question but I have been unable to get a definitive answer from the Xen docs.
Is it possible to manage multiple hardware devices under a Xen hypervisor?  IOW, Is the XEN hypervisor a layer spanning several devices, thus making it scalable and redundant? 
THanks

Lawrence

Comment: Can you rewrite this question please, it's hard to understand what you mean - what do you mean by 'device'?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this scalability and redundancy level is achieveable on xen or any other  hypervisor. That would have to be like a single operating system running on many servers, and only thing that comes to my mind like is IBM's parallel sysplex on mainframes.
You should look for some clusters between domU's instead of dom0's.

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't yet tried this myself, Xen 4.0.1 supports :"Remus Fault Tolerance: Live transactional synchronization of VM state between physical servers. run guests synchronized on multiple hosts simultaneously for preventing downtime from hardware failures. Remus support in Xen 4.0.0 requires linux-2.6.18-xen dom0 kernel. Pvops dom0 kernel (2.6.32) support for Remus is available in Xen 4.0.1. For more information see Remus wiki page"

Note that scalability and redundancy aren't necessarily related. Usually you get either redundancy (i.e. RAID1) or scalability (i.e. RAID0)

More info on Remus is available on http://wiki.xen.org/xenwiki/Remus

If you don't require quite as high redundancy as Remus (apparently) can provide, Xen also provides "ordinary" live migration og VMs between different Xen-domains.
Either way, one single Xen hypervisor won't do what you're asking for. Every server must run it's own hypervisor, but they can be configured to provide RAID1-type redundancy.